# Error after installing the ggplot2. How can I solve it?

Tags: r

After installing ggplot2 I am trying to run the library.But it shows the error message :

```
       Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), 
     versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
     there is no package called ‘Rcpp’
      Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’
    Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), 
     versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
         there is no package called ‘Rcpp’
        Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’
```

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
remove.packages(c("ggplot2", "data.table"))
install.packages('Rcpp', dependencies = TRUE)
install.packages('ggplot2', dependencies = TRUE)
install.packages('data.table', dependencies = TRUE)
```

Comment: I tried this .But still it shows the error message.